# Regex for float with comma

Tags: javascript

I need to validate an input, contains price of an item.
The value could be..

```
1.2
1.02 
30,000 
30,000.00 
30000000
```

So I need the regex to support this.

Comment: Show us what code you have so far.

Comment: Also, why do you think you need a regex?

Comment: Currently I am using following regex
/^(?:[1-9]\d{0,2}(?:,\d{3})*|0)(?:\.\d+)?$/

But with this when I am trying for 30000 its not working

Comment: Impossible without knowing the locale. E.g. 1.234 is one thousand, two hundred and thirty four in France.

Comment: Not sure what kind of validations you're trying to do, but I'm almost certain you won't need a regex. Can you add more details to your question?

Comment: I have a text box where user can enter price.
I need to vaidate for correct price value like

1.2
1.02 
30,000 
30,000.00 
30000000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Came up with this:

```
^\d+([\,]\d+)*([\.]\d+)?$
```

Regex for detecting if it is a price. Breaking it down into parts:

```
^     # start of string
\d+   # this matches at least 1 digit (and is greedy; it matches as many as possible)

(     # start of capturing group
 [\,] # matcher group with an escaped comma inside
 \d+  # same thing as above; matches at least 1 digit and as many as possible
)*    # end of capturing group, which is repeated 0 or more times
      # this allows prices with and without commas.

(     # start of capturing group
 [\.] # matcher group with an escaped fullstop inside
 \d+  # same thing; refer to above
)?    # end of capturing group, which is optional.
      # this allows a decimal to be optional
$     # end of string
```

I'd recommend you to try http://regex101.com when you want to create a regex.

Answer (score 2):

That should work

```
/^[0-9]{1,3}(?:\,[0-9]{3})*(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

Comment: You can replace `[0-9]`by \d

Answer (score 0):

this should work

```
^(?:[1-9]\d*|0)?(?:\.\d+)?$
```